# Calling a Stored Procedure when you DON'T have the parameter name

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic, vb6

This may be a dumb question, but I can't find an answer.

I'm working in Classic ASP for the first time, trying to reformat the code to secure it against SQL injection. I've got the format and whatnot to make these changes (not the issue here), but one of the files is "generic". It gets the sproc name and parameters passed in and the SQL statement is constructed into a string. It's called by some 50+ other files. Since a SQL statement string was originally being used, and since it's been "genericized", there are no parameter names to put into my CreateParameter method. IS IT POSSIBLE TO CREATE A PARAMETER WITH NO NAME? (i.e. "@myParameterName") If Not, is there some other way to accoplish what I'm trying to do?

```
Set cnnSQLServer = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnnSQLServer.Open Application("xyz_ConnectionString")
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnnSQLServer
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@MyParameterName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 100, myValueToPass)
cmd.Parameters.Append(param1)
Set rstData = cmd.Execute
```

Thanks!

Comment: When using classic ADO with SQL Server OLEDB provider, `ADODB.Command` always passes parameters to stored procedures by position. Parameters names are ignored even if supplied, they are just used as keys in `Command`'s internal `Parameters` collection. This is different in ADO.Net now.

Comment: You should "answer" this question. That way I can check it as correct. Thank you for the info!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using classic ADO with SQL Server OLEDB provider, `ADODB.Command` always passes parameters to stored procedures by position. Parameters names are ignored even if supplied, they are just used as keys in `Command`'s internal `Parameters` collection. This is different in ADO.Net now.